Number of ways of giving $n$ identical gifts to $k$ children
I'm wondering what's the number of ways of giving $n$ identical gifts to $k$ (distinct) children with no restrictions so any child can receive between $0$ to $n$ gifts. My initial thought is to take cases where we give $n$ gifts to $1$ child, $n-1$ gifts to $1$ child and $1$ gift to one of the remaining and then $n-2$ gifts to $1$ child, $2$ gifts to one of the remaining or $1$ gift to $2$ remaining children and so on. This gets roughly the series:
$\binom{k}{1} + \binom{k}{2} +\left(\binom{k}{2} + \binom{k}{3}\right) + \left(\binom{k}{2} + \binom{k}{3} +\binom{k}{4}\right) + ... + \left(\binom{k}{2} + \binom{k}{3} + \binom{k}{4}+...+ \binom{k}{n}\right)$
But I know this method overcounts because giving $1$ gift to $1$ child and then $n-1$ gifts to a remaining child is the same as giving $n-1$ gifts to $1$ child and then $1$ gifts to a remaining child. I could try resolving this by stopping at $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ to get:
$\binom{k}{1} + \big(\lceil n/2 \rceil -1\big)\binom{k}{2} + \big(\lceil n/2 \rceil -2\big)\binom{k}{3}+...+\binom{k}{\lceil n/2 \rceil}$
This doesn't seem simplifiable and  I also run into the problem of assuming in my series that $k≥\lceil n/2 \rceil$ but if $k≤\lceil n/2 \rceil$ I run into trouble trying to divvy up the gifts like this. Could someone lend a helping hand with this thank you!

This is the classic stars-and-bars problem.  Once you learn that technique, it's very easy to see that the answer is $\displaystyle \binom{n+k-1}{n}$.

Have a look at stars and bars.

There is a simple way to get the answer.Imagine you somehow borrowed $ k $ gifts from $ k $ children. Now you have $ n+k $ identical gifts, and you have to distribute them to $ k $ children, to be fair, you should return the one gift you borrowed from each child. So each child get at least one gift,  $ n+ k \\$ in total and it is easy to get the number of ways is
$ \\C_{n+k-1}^{k-1} \\ $. (Choose $ k-1$ in $n+k-1$ to "split" the gifts to $ k $ parts, each part has at least one gift )

Since the gifts are identical, the difference will only come when two kids have different number of gifts.
Let the first child have $x_1$ gifts and the second child have $x_2$ gifts and so on.
According to your attempt, it is clear that we have to distribute all the $n$ gifts, which actually makes the problem quite easy.
We can say that 
$\displaystyle x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=n$
We have to find number of non-negative integer solutions of this equation.
This is nothing but $$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$

This can be shown easily by the method of generating functions.
